# Как задать размеры виджетов в процентах от размера экрана

Tags: android, android-layout

Так уж случилось, что все элементы в моём активити надо расположить по %. Простейший способ у меня не прошёл:

```
android:layout_width="100%"
```

Какой есть способ расположить элементы, используя абсолютную(%) вёрстку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не так давно *Google* представила новую библиотеку поддержки [*support:percent*](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html), которая позволяет задавать некоторые параметры виджетов в процентах от общего размера контейнера.

Библиотека включает в себя 2 контейнера, которые поддерживают указание вложенных в них элементов в процентах: [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) и [`PercentFrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html). Свойства контейнеров аналогичны "старшим" братьям, так же они позволяют указать некоторые параметры в процентах.

**Пример 1:**

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_widthPercent="35%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="10%"
    app:layout_marginStartPercent="10%"
    android:text="Some text" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Another some text"
    app:layout_marginEndPercent="10%"
    app:layout_marginRightPercent="10%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="35%" />
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

**Пример 2:**

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%" />
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Для того, чтобы подключить библиотеку, в секцию `dependencies` файла *build.gradle* приложения необходимо добавить зависимость:

`compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'`

*23.0.0* - текущая последняя версия библиотеки, может изменится со временем.

[Больше подробностей по использованию](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/)

Answer (score 9):

Оборачиваем в LinearLayout, для дочерних элементов выставляем нужный layout_weight.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<!-- Эта кнопка занимает 30% от всей ширины -->
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3" />

<!-- Эта - 50% -->
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<!-- А эта - 20% -->
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: weight это ширина. А как изменить высоту. А расстояние от бока (top, left)?

Comment: Горизонтальные отступы - так же, вставляем View-распорку, ставим ему нужный layout_weight.


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <!-- Отступ слева в 20% -->
 <View
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="0.2" />
 <Button
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="0.8" />

    </LinearLayout>

С вертикальными отступами и высотой так, увы, сделать не получится, это уже только программно.

Comment: @falstaf а как программно? Либо напишите код, либо дайте линки на мануалы по этой теме, плиз.

Answer (score 0):

> Цитата: 
> weight это ширина.

weight - "вес" объекта или те самые проценты в зависимости от заданной ориентации: в данном случае, т.к. ориентация layout горизонтальная, то можно сказать, что это ширина.

Можно создать стиль, в котором будут указаны необходимые атрибуты. В последствии этот стиль можно применять к любой кнопке.