# Размерность компонентов в процентах от величины экрана

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Есть, к примеру, следующая задача:

> Должно быть представлено меню, состоящее из четырех кнопок. Высота кнопок должна составлять 15% от высоты экрана. Расстояние между кнопками – 7%. Первая и последняя кнопка должны быть на равном расстоянии от краев экрана. Ширина кнопок 60%, выравнивание посередине.

Сама задача вполне ясна, однако появилась проблема в выборе инструментария и способа реализации.
Какой `Layout` лучше подойдет для данной задачи? Пробовал реализовать через `ConstraintLayout` и `LinearLayout`(задавал в `activity.xml`), но после долгих игр со свойствами кнопок ни к какому адекватному варианту не пришел. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184939) в ответах не нашлось актуального рабочего способа, да и про свойства `margin` нет ничего...

Также был бы рад примерам реализации подобной задачи.